# How to automatically pick file as kafka producer's input?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I just started learning Kafka. I did lots googlings but still have no clue: how can I automatically pick up files dropped in a folder as the input of producer and hence get picked up by consumer? Thank you. 
As a start point, I tried the following code and it doesn't work (simply exit with no error):

```
./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list sandbox.hortonworks.com:6667 --topic kafka-topic1 < test.csv
```

[image]

Below is update:

I tried more exactly the same way I create producer and consumer, I saw once that consumer received the csv content line by line, BUT, not complete.
I tried immediately again, I don't see the result any more.
I then did the console-producer and the consumer received messages, right after it I did file input, the consumer received but in bad sequence, please refer to the screenshots.

test.csv:

[image]

producer:

[image]

Consumer:

[image]

Terminate console-producer and start file producer

[image]

Nothing happens in consumer:

[image]

Terminate consumer and restart it after restart producer(file):
Consumer received the file:

[image]

Please note the sequence is not in the original order

run producer again, consumer receives it again:

[image]

Sequence seems "wrong" again?

Anyway, very unstable here, any clue?

BTW: I tested my Internet connection speed and both download and upload are around 10Mb/s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka Console Producer is not designed for this use case. Have a look into Kafka Connect -- it allows to setup continuous import for files:

http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-filestream/filestream_connector.html

Comment: Thank you Matthias, it's part of confluent solution, right? can you share any working complete example without using confluent or other third party tools? or it is just the most common practice to use third party tools like confluent? Thanks.

Comment: Kafka Connect itself is part of Apache Kafka -- thus, Connect is not provided by Confluent. However, Kafka Connect is a framework that need actual connectors -- and Apache Kafka does not ship any connectors. There are many open source connectors you can use -- include those provided by Confluent (Confluent also offers some proprietary connector with Confluent Enterprise). Thus, if you don't want to write your own connector, you will need to use a "third party" connector.

Comment: I recommend to use Confluent connector (but I might be biased, as I work at Confluent) because those are of very high quality. Furthermore, those connectors are fully compatible with Apache Kafka -- thus, you do not need to worry about "vendor lock in" or similar and you do not need to use Confluent Open Source if you want to use them. See this list of certified connectors (from Confluent and others "third party" vendors and OS community): https://www.confluent.io/product/connectors/

Comment: CP docs http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect should provide all information you need to setup Kafka Connect (suitable for Apache Kafka and Confluent Platform) and to configure a connector. You can also have a look into Apache Kafka docs: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect

Comment: Thank you Matthias, I will give it a try tonight

Comment: This might help, too: http://www.landoop.com/blog/2017/02/ftp-to-kafka/

Comment: I've tried again, please see update in my original post above, thank you.